# cshtml file is not accepting in server it shows the error "does not inherit from 'System.Web.WebPages.WebPage'."

Tags: speak, sitecore-rocks

I am working on speak-ui. I have created one view (`mybutton.cshtml`) under `sitecore/client/speak/Your Apps/App/` in the core database. When i am trying to see the preview page it shows

> Type 'ASP._Page_sitecore_shell_client_App_myButton_cshtml' does not inherit from 'System.Web.WebPages.WebPage'

[image: Screenshot Error]

Here is my code:

`mybutton.cshtml`:

```
@model Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel
@{
}
<div>
<h1>Hello world</h1>
</div>
```

I added these lines in web.config file (`C://windows/Microsoft.net/Framework64/config/`) also.

```
 <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="true"/>
```

if I add below code in cshtml.

```
@inherits Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel
```

I am getting below error

[image]

Can anyone suggest how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue Resolved

**Cause of Issue**:
Created a Sitecore Item with basic template under /sitecore/client/Your Apps and browsed by using the physical path of the layout.

**Solution**:
Created a Sitecore Item under /sitecore/client/Your Apps using Speak related templates using sitecore rocks. 
Assigned a relevant layout and browsed that item with Sitecore Item path as url (sitecoreinstance/itempath).